# How to build a slider or JCarousel 100% width and previous and next Image with 25% width?

Tags: theming, javascript

I need to build a Carousel with the following specs:

- width 100%, height 600px
- show 3 items, (previous only 25% screenwidth, current and centered 50% screenwidth and Next also 25% screenwidth). so previous and next item are shown only half.
- layout is responsive (tablet and desktop 3 items, mobile 1 item)

I tried [JCarousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/jcarousel), [OWl Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/owlcarousel). But JCarousel shows always full items and not centered. OWL Carousel 2 did work correctly with views (Views 3.8, Jquery Update 2.4, OWL Carousel 2 Dev Version). That is unfortunate because the specs here http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/center.html showing exactly what i need (only with 5 images). 
Did anyone built something similar? Maybe is it possible with adjusting the JCarousel CSS or is there also Javascript needed.

Comment: please show your research effort, we are here help you but dont ask to give me fulll fledge solution.

Comment: sorry i already tried a lot and don't need a full solution. i only wanted to be as specific as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work somehow with css, but had some bugs when trying to skip to the next item infinitly.

Now it works better with [Flexslider](https://www.drupal.org/project/flexslider) and i applied this css http://jsfiddle.net/Y3kx5/2/.